# jquery tokeninput input parameter missing

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, jquery-tokeninput

I am following railscasts episode 258 about jquery tokeninput.

I do not know why the user's input does not reach the input parameter for the users query?

My database is postgres.

pharmacies controller

```
    def index
      @pharmacies = Pharmacy.order(:name)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render json: @pharmacies.tokens(params[:q]) }
      end
    end
```

user model

```
  def pharmacy_tokens=(tokens)
    self.pharmacy_ids = Pharmacy.ids_from_tokens(tokens)
  end
```

pharmacy model

```
  def self.tokens(query)
    pharmacies = where('lower(name) LIKE ? or name LIKE ?', "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%")
    if pharmacies.empty?
      [{id: "<<<#{query}>>>", name: "New: \"#{query}\""}]
    else
      pharmacies
    end
  end
```

users view

```
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :pharmacy_tokens, "Pharmacies" %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :pharmacy_tokens, data: {load: @user.pharmacies} %>
    </div>
```

users's.js.coffee

```
    jQuery ->
    $('#user_pharmacy_tokens').tokenInput '/pharmacies.json'
    theme: 'facebook'
    prePopulate: $('#user_pharmacy_tokens').data('load')
    preventDuplicates: true
    queryParam: "q"
```

Result

```
    Processing by PharmaciesController#index as JSON
    Parameters: {"locale"=>"en"}
    (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "pharmacies" WHERE (lower(name) LIKE '%%' or name LIKE '%%')
    Pharmacy Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "pharmacies".* FROM "pharmacies" WHERE (lower(name) LIKE '%%' or name LIKE '%%') ORDER BY pharmacies.name ASC, name
    Completed 200 OK in 30ms (Views: 27.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
```

When typing into the text_field the javascript works, it's just that the text is no longer in the query... just my empty 'like' percent signs.. '%%'. What happened to my input here?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these. Mostly first one.

```
1. Try %#{query}% without double quotes.
2. Try %query% without double quotes
```

Let me know which one works.

Comment: both dont work, when removing the double quotes the where clause regex is no longer valid. I tried single quotes as well and although it is a valid regex, the string NOT the query parameter is passed into the query.. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "pharmacies" WHERE (lower(name) LIKE '%#{query}%' or name LIKE '%#{query}%')`

Comment: is the locale parameter causing this? `Processing by PharmaciesController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"en"}
  [1m[36mPharmacy Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "pharmacies".* FROM "pharmacies" WHERE (name ILIKE '%%') ORDER BY pharmacies.name ASC, name[0m
Completed 200 OK in 30ms (Views: 28.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)`

Comment: Are you getting params[:q] in your controller?

Comment: Also put comma between jQuery token input options in JS. Remove queryParam from options as it is by default passed as q. Put comma like

Comment: I added the commas, but the value is still no being passed in. I'm not sure what you mean by your first question.. "Are you getting params[:q] in your controller?" @kashyap

Comment: I also removed the unnecessary queryParam from the users coffee script.

Comment: i meant what is the value of params[:q] when received in controller. You can check that on terminal if in development mode.

Comment: also put %static_string% in your quey in pharmacy model, instead of your variable and then check.

Comment: the static string query works... but I see nothing in my development log/console output about the parameter being passed into the controller.. I am trying to figure out how to test this in the console. p.s. thanks for being patient, i am obviously new to this.